# Show that $(A \cup B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that the complement of the union of two sets is equal to the complement of one set union with the complement of the other set.

Algebraically; $(A \cup B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$

Not sure how to prove this using the definition of sets, would greatly appreciate an explanation.

Comment: It's not true.... look at a Venn diagram.

Comment: Indeed, $(A \cup B)^c = A^c \cap B^c$!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Properties

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, that's not true. The right relation is $(A\cup B)^c=A^c \cap B^c$.

It is instructive to see the proof of any such relations, but you have to work out all the others by yourself. The most direct way that I know to prove that two sets are equal is to prove that one set contains the other first, then proving that the other set contains the first.

We start by proving $(A\cup B)^c\subset A^c \cap B^c$, by taking an element $p\in (A\cup B)^c$ and proving that it is in $A^c\cap B^c$. If $p\in (A\cup B)^c$, then surely $p$ does not belong to the union $A\cup B$, so it belongs neither to $A$ nor to $B$. That is, it belongs to $A^c$ and $B^c$, so it is in their intersection: $p\in (A\cup B)^c\implies p\in A^c\cap B^c\implies (A\cup B)^c\subset A^c\cap B^c$.

We now prove $A^c\cap B^c\subset (A\cup B)^c$. Let $p\in A^c\cap B^c$: then $p$ belongs contemporarily to $A^c$ and $B^c$. This means that $p$ is neither in $A$ nor in $B$, so it belongs to the complement of their union. So $p\in A^c\cap B^c\implies p\in(A\cup B)^c\implies A^c\cap B^c\subset (A\cup B)^c$.

Having shown those two facts, we can conclude $(A\cup B)^c=A^c \cap B^c$.